# DocuSign JWT Access Token Request

Tags: vb.net, jwt, token, docusignapi

- I'm trying to get access token within sandbox environment.
- I've a VB.NET application and referenced DocuSign.eSign.dll
- I examined docusign C# code examples and could not get them run in vb.net

This is the first approach I tried:

```
Dim ac As ApiClient = New ApiClient()
Dim privateKeyStream() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(PrivateKey)
Dim tokenInfo As OAuth.OAuthToken = ac.RequestJWTUserToken("INTEGRATION_ID", "ACCOUNT_ID", "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token", privateKeyStream, 1)
```

This resulted in the following error:

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Unexpected PEM type
  Source=DocuSign.eSign
  StackTrace:
   at DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiClient.CreateRSAKeyFromPem(String key) ...
```

Second approach was using the following codes:

```
Dim privateKeyStream As Stream = New FileStream("D:\docusign.pem", FileMode.Open)
'Dim privateKeyStream As Stream = New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PK))
Using SR = New StreamReader(privateKeyStream)
    If Not SR Is Nothing And SR.Peek() > 0 Then
        Dim privateKeyBytes() As Byte = ReadAsBytes(privateKeyStream)
        'Dim privateKeyBytes() As Byte = StreamToByteArray(privateKeyStream)
        'Dim privateKeyBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(PrivateKey)
        'Dim privateKeyBytes() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PrivateKey)

        Dim privateKeyS As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(privateKeyBytes)

        Dim handler As JwtSecurityTokenHandler = New JwtSecurityTokenHandler()
        handler.SetDefaultTimesOnTokenCreation = False

        Dim descriptor As SecurityTokenDescriptor = New SecurityTokenDescriptor()
        descriptor.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
        descriptor.IssuedAt = DateTime.UtcNow

        Dim scopes As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        scopes.Add(OAuth.Scope_SIGNATURE)

        descriptor.Subject = New ClaimsIdentity()
        descriptor.Subject.AddClaim(New Claim("scope", String.Join(" ", scopes)))
        descriptor.Subject.AddClaim(New Claim("aud", "account-d.docusign.com"))
        descriptor.Subject.AddClaim(New Claim("iss", "INTEGRATION_ID"))
        descriptor.Subject.AddClaim(New Claim("sub", "ACCOUNT_ID"))

        Dim RSA = CreateRSAKeyFromPem(privateKeyS)
        Dim rsaKey As RsaSecurityKey = New RsaSecurityKey(RSA)
        descriptor.SigningCredentials = New SigningCredentials(rsaKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature)


        Dim Token = handler.CreateToken(descriptor)
        Dim jwtToken As String = handler.WriteToken(Token)

        Dim baseUri As String = String.Format("https://{0}/", basePath)
        Dim RestClient As RestClient = New RestClient(baseUri)
        RestClient.Timeout = 10000

        Dim contentType As String = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

        Dim formParams As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        formParams.Add("grant_type", OAuth.Grant_Type_JWT)
        formParams.Add("assertion", jwtToken)

        Dim queryParams As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        Dim headerParams As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        headerParams.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        headerParams.Add("Cache-Control", "no-store")
        headerParams.Add("Pragma", "no-cache")

        Dim fileParams As New Dictionary(Of String, FileParameter)
        Dim pathParams As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        Dim postBody As Object = Nothing

        Dim request As RestRequest = PrepareRequest(basePath, Method.POST, queryParams, postBody, headerParams, formParams, fileParams, pathParams, contentType)

        Dim response As IRestResponse = RestClient.Execute(request)

        If (response.StatusCode >= HttpStatusCode.OK And response.StatusCode < HttpStatusCode.BadRequest) Then
            Dim tokenInfo As OAuth.OAuthToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of OAuth.OAuthToken)(response.Content)
            Return tokenInfo.access_token
        Else
            Throw New ApiException(response.StatusCode, "Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code " & response.ResponseStatus & " with response Body: " + response.Content, response.Content)
        End If
    Else
        Throw New ApiException(400, "Private key stream not supplied or is invalid!")
    End If
End Using
```

This resulted in the same as the first solution:

```
System.Exception
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Unexpected PEM type
  Source=PropertyServer
  StackTrace:
   at PropertyServer.classDocusign.CreateRSAKeyFromPem(String key) in...
```

And my 3rd approach was like the following:

```
Dim ar1 As JObject = New JObject()
ar1.Add("typ", "JWT")
ar1.Add("alg", "RS256")

Dim header As String = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(ar1.ToString)

Dim ar2 As JObject = New JObject()
ar2.Add("iss", "INTEGRATION_ID")
ar2.Add("sub", "ACCOUNT_ID")
ar2.Add("iat", DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, New Date(1970, 1, 1), Now))
ar2.Add("exp:", DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, New Date(1970, 1, 1), DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, 1, Now)))
ar2.Add("aud:", "account-d.docusign.com")
ar2.Add("scope", "signature impersonation")

Dim body As String = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(ar2.ToString)

Dim stringToSign As String = header & "." & body

Dim bytesToSign() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)

'Dim data() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PrivateKey)
'Dim b64 As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)

Dim keyBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(PrivateKey)

Dim privKeyObj = Asn1Object.FromByteArray(keyBytes)
Dim privStruct = RsaPrivateKeyStructure.GetInstance(privKeyObj)

Dim sig As ISigner = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA")

sig.Init(True, New RsaKeyParameters(True, privStruct.Modulus, privStruct.PrivateExponent))

sig.BlockUpdate(bytesToSign, 0, bytesToSign.Length)
Dim signature() As Byte = sig.GenerateSignature()

Dim sign As String = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(signature)

Return header & "." & body & "." & sign
```

At my 3rt try I was able to get result however when I try to post this as assertion part of the request in Postman, it returns the following:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "no_valid_keys_or_signatures"
}
```

I've spent hours to solve the issue but no luck, thanks in advance.

Note: These are imported

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text
Imports DocuSign.eSign.Api
Imports DocuSign.eSign.Client
Imports DocuSign.eSign.Client.Auth
Imports DocuSign.eSign.Model
Imports Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Cryptography.Algorithms
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.Security
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Pkcs
Imports RestSharp
Imports System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
Imports System.Security.Claims
Imports Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your third approach was best. Especially since your claims were not correct. They should be:

```
ar2.Add("iss", "INTEGRATION_ID")
# sub is NOT the account id
ar2.Add("sub", "GUID_VERSION_OF_USER_ID")
# Check that your date is correct
ar2.Add("iat", DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, New Date(1970, 1, 1), Now))
# should be exp, not exp:
ar2.Add("exp", DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, New Date(1970, 1, 1), 
DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, 1, Now)))
# should be "aud", not "aud:"
ar2.Add("aud", "account-d.docusign.com")
# only need signature. impersonation is automatically implied.
ar2.Add("scope", "signature")
```

I was unable to find anything very useful for creating an RS256 JWT via VB.

[This company](https://www.example-code.com/vbnet/jwt_rsa_create.asp) offers something for a fee but I have no experience with it.

Microsoft apparently now enables the creation of RS256 JWTs but doesn't have a useful example that I could find. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.createencodedjwt?view=azure-dotnet#System_IdentityModel_Tokens_Jwt_JwtSecurityTokenHandler_CreateEncodedJwt_System_String_System_String_System_Security_Claims_ClaimsIdentity_System_Nullable_System_DateTime__System_Nullable_System_DateTime__System_Nullable_System_DateTime__Microsoft_IdentityModel_Tokens_SigningCredentials_).

**Please submit an answer to your own question once you've figured it out. Thank you!!**

### Added

I suggest printing out the JWT that your software produces, then use a verification tool or procedure to verify that the JWT that your software produces is what you expected.

Unfortunately, many of the online verifiers just decode the claims. You need to additionally check that the signature is correct. (Use the public key from the RSA pair that DocuSign gives you.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've applied your fixes including GUID_VERSION_OF_USER_ID

Comment: * I've applied your fixes related to typos
* Updated sub value according to Sandbox > Settings > API & Keys > User ID
* Only included signature in the scope
* Tried to update iat and exp values according to both UTC and local time
* Tried to remove iat and exp values from the request

Nothing has changed so far :/

Comment: See my addition to my answer. Add the JWT that your software produces to your question (edit your question), along with the public key for your integration key.

Comment: @LarryK can you please look into my question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62873306/the-recipient-you-have-identified-is-not-a-valid-recipient-of-the-specified-enve

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working with the help of Larry K!
I'm not sure what I missed again after Larry's response yesterday, but I'm able to get access token now with the following codes: (By the way setting iat and exp to UTC or local time does not make difference)

...Addinionally PriveKey declaration like follows:

```
Dim PrivateKey As String = "MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAjtTe7UUP/CBI9s...BLABLABLA...JfwZ2hHqFPXA9ecbhc0".Replace(vbLf, "").Replace(vbCr, "")

Dim ar1 As JObject = New JObject()
ar1.Add("typ", "JWT")
ar1.Add("alg", "RS256")

Dim header As String = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(ar1.ToString)

Dim ar2 As JObject = New JObject()
ar2.Add("iss", "INTEGRATION_ID")
ar2.Add("sub", "GUID_VERSION_OF_USER_ID")
ar2.Add("iat", DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, New Date(1970, 1, 1), Now().ToUniversalTime))
ar2.Add("exp", DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, New Date(1970, 1, 1), DateAdd(DateInterval.Hour, 1, Now().ToUniversalTime)))
ar2.Add("aud", "account-d.docusign.com")
ar2.Add("scope", "signature")

Dim body As String = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(ar2.ToString)

Dim stringToSign As String = header & "." & body

Dim bytesToSign() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)

Dim keyBytes() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(PrivateKey)

Dim privKeyObj = Asn1Object.FromByteArray(keyBytes)
Dim privStruct = RsaPrivateKeyStructure.GetInstance(privKeyObj)

Dim sig As ISigner = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withRSA")

sig.Init(True, New RsaKeyParameters(True, privStruct.Modulus, privStruct.PrivateExponent))

sig.BlockUpdate(bytesToSign, 0, bytesToSign.Length)
Dim signature() As Byte = sig.GenerateSignature()

Dim sign As String = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(signature)

Return header & "." & body & "." & sign
```

Thanks a lot Larry K!